# Listview items are not clicked on API 19, but clicked on upper API's

Tags: android, listview, google-api

I am trying to develop a music player app.

First, i am choosing a music from listview. Then music playing screen opens with chosen music. At the same time a notification appears. Wherever you are, if you click the notification, music player screen is opened with current music. Then if you want, you can go to music list by pressing back button.

On API 19's; after coming notification to music playing screen and press back button, music list is shown but items are not being clicked. But higher API's there is no problem.

The only trouble; after coming from notification panel on API 19.

I couldn't understand the problem. Music List onCreate method is below.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.showmusicfiles);

    filesFound=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.files_found);
    items = new ArrayList<FileItem>();

    context = getApplicationContext();

   String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
           File.separator + "MusicApp"+File.separator+"mp3";
     File f = new File(path);
    final File fileList[] = f.listFiles();
    for (File file : f.listFiles()) {

        FileItem item=new FileItem();
        item.setDescription(file.getName());
        item.setFullPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
        items.add(item);
    }

    searchResults=sortByDate(items);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<FileItem>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.music_file_item, searchResults){
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.music_file_item, parent, false);
            }

            TextView description = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.file_description);

            final FileItem searchResult = searchResults.get(position);
            description.setText(searchResult.getDescription().replace(".mp3",""));

            convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            switch (which){
                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                    deleteFileFromList(searchResults.get(position).getFullPath(),position);
                                    break;

                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                    toast("yoh dedın");
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ShowMusicFiles.this);
                    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                            .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();


                    return true;
                }
            });



            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    FileTypeList = new ArrayList<File>();
                    FileTypeList = FileItemToFile(searchResults);
                    DescriptionList= new ArrayList<String>();
                    DescriptionList = getDescriptionList(searchResults);

                    playerIntent = new Intent(context, MusicPlayer.class);
                    playerIntent.putExtra("songPosition",position);
                    playerIntent.putExtra("songList",FileTypeList);
                    playerIntent.putExtra("descriptionList",DescriptionList);
                    playerIntent.putExtra("fromWhere","musicList");

                    playerIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(playerIntent);
                }
            });
            return convertView;
        }
    };

    filesFound.setAdapter(adapter);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    final ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view_music);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

My back press method on the music playing screen is only included an intent to go music list page. So i dont think i need to write to music play codes.

Thanks.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent goToMusicList = new Intent(MusicPlayer.this,ShowMusicFiles.class);
    startActivity(goToMusicList);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using android:clickable="true" in R.layout.music_file_item? Or convertView.setClickable(true)?

Comment: On layout file, clickable is already added. I also tried form java code, but it didn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

call `filesFOund.invalidate()` before `filesFound.setAdapter(adapter)`. If that does not solve the problem, then try setting the launchMode of ShowMusicFiles activity to singleTop.